# Promises do not work (for me)

Tags: sapui5

Probably I'm missing something basic here. Scenario goes like this:

Within the root view controller of my application (App.controller.js, `onInit` function) I'm performing a series of read operations on a named model in order to have additional data ready mainly for use by formatters in subsequent views. What I have done is using promises to make sure that data will be ready.

Problem is that **application occasionally crashes when the initial view** with pattern `""` (Worklist.view.xml in my case) **is loaded after the root view** (App.view.xml) because the formatter function can't find the data expected. Added a few break-points and observed the debugger:

1. stopping at the first read function
2. stopping at the promises condition at the end
3. stopping (and throwing error) at the formatter function at the subsequent view
4. stopping in the success function of oData read (resolve)
5. page freezes afterwards as result of the exception thrown above

"Normal" flow, when application doesn't crash goes like this:

1. stopping at the first read function
2. stopping at the promises condition at the end
3. stopping in the success function of oData read (resolve)
4. stopping at the readyToGo function (it's there just for temporary debugging)
5. stopping at the formatter function at the subsequent view
6. page display, everything in order

Judging by the above, I have reached the conclusion that my promises do not work. Any ideas?

---

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "kristal/apps/agreements/controller/BaseController",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function (BaseController, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  /* PROMISE VARIABLES */
  var oModelTypeDataDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  var oModelStatusDataDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  var oModelRoleDataDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  var oModelRefDataDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  var oModelExtOrgDataDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  var oModelInvolvementDataDeferred = jQuery.Deferred();

  return BaseController.extend("kristal.apps.agreements.controller.App", {
    onInit: function () {
      /* CALLED AFTER PROMISES HAVE BEEN FULFILLED */
      var readyToGo = function() { 
        jQuery.sap.log.error("Ready!");
      };
      var oViewModel;
      var fnSetAppNotBusy;
      var iOriginalBusyDelay = this.getView().getBusyIndicatorDelay();
      var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
        busy: true,
        delay: 0
      });
      this.setModel(oViewModel, "appView");
      fnSetAppNotBusy = function() {
        oViewModel.setProperty("/busy", false);
        oViewModel.setProperty("/delay", iOriginalBusyDelay);
      };
      this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().metadataLoaded().then(fnSetAppNotBusy);
      var oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel("f4");
      /* oData READ OPS */
      oModel.metadataLoaded().then(function(){
        // Initialize additional data
        var sPath = "/Agreement_TypesSet";
        oModel.read(sPath, {
          success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oModelTypeDataDeferred.resolve();
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("Error", oError);
          }
        }); 
        sPath = "/Agreement_StatusesSet";
        oModel.read(sPath, {
          success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oModelStatusDataDeferred.resolve();
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("Error", oError);
          }
        });
        sPath = "/Role_TypesSet";
        oModel.read(sPath, {
          success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oModelRoleDataDeferred.resolve();
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("Error", oError);
          }
        });
        sPath = "/Reference_TypesSet";
        oModel.read(sPath, {
          success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oModelRefDataDeferred.resolve();
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("Error", oError);
          }
        });
        sPath = "/External_OrganizationsSet";
        oModel.read(sPath, {
          success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oModelRefDataDeferred.resolve();
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("Error", oError);
          }
        });
        sPath = "/Involvement_TypesSet";
        oModel.read(sPath, {
          success: function(oData, oResponse) {
            oModelInvolvementDataDeferred.resolve();
          },
          error: function(oError) {
            jQuery.sap.log.error("Error", oError);
          }
        });
        /* IF ALL PROMISES FULFILLED, PROCEED */
        jQuery.when(oModelTypeDataDeferred, oModelStatusDataDeferred, oModelRoleDataDeferred, oModelRefDataDeferred, oModelExtOrgDataDeferred, oModelInvolvementDataDeferred)
          .done().then(jQuery.proxy(readyToGo, this));
    },
    // ...
  });
});
```

manifest.json:

```json
{
  "_version": "1.4.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "kristal.apps.agreements",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "dataSources": {
      "mainService": {
        "uri": "/DEV/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZCONTRACTS_SRV/",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "2.0",
          "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
      }
    },
    "sourceTemplate": {
      "id": "sap.ui.ui5-template-plugin.1worklist",
      "version": "1.38.3"
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
      "icon": "sap-icon://task",
      "favIcon": "",
      "phone": "",
      "phone@2": "",
      "tablet": "",
      "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
      "desktop": true,
      "tablet": true,
      "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": [
      "sap_hcb",
      "sap_bluecrystal"
    ]
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
      "viewName": "kristal.apps.agreements.view.App",
      "type": "XML",
      "id": "app",
      "async": true
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.38.0",
      "libs": {
        "sap.ui.core": {
          "minVersion": "1.38.0"
        },
        "sap.m": {
          "minVersion": "1.38.0"
        },
        "sap.ushell": {
          "minVersion": "1.38.0"
        },
        "sap.collaboration": {
          "minVersion": "1.38",
          "lazy": true
        }
      }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
      "compact": true,
      "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
      "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
          "bundleName": "kristal.apps.agreements.i18n.i18n"
        }
      },
      "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "preload": true,
        "settings": {
          "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
        }
      },
      "f4": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "preload": true,
        "settings": {
          "metadataUrlParams": {
            "sap-documentation": "heading"
          },
          "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
        }
      }
    },
    "routing": {
      "config": {
        "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
        "viewType": "XML",
        "viewPath": "kristal.apps.agreements.view",
        "controlId": "app",
        "controlAggregation": "pages",
        "bypassed": {
          "target": [
            "notFound"
          ]
        },
        "async": true
      },
      "routes": [{
        "pattern": "",
        "name": "worklist",
        "target": [
          "worklist"
        ]
      }, {
        "pattern": "AgreementsSet/{objectId}",
        "name": "object",
        "target": [
          "object"
        ]
      }],
      "targets": {
        "worklist": {
          "viewName": "Worklist",
          "viewId": "worklist",
          "viewLevel": 1
        },
        "object": {
          "viewName": "Object",
          "viewId": "object",
          "viewLevel": 2
        },
        "objectNotFound": {
          "viewName": "ObjectNotFound",
          "viewId": "objectNotFound"
        },
        "notFound": {
          "viewName": "NotFound",
          "viewId": "notFound"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sap.platform.abap": {
    "uri": "/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/zctr_contr_mnt/webapp",
    "_version": "1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Component.js

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "sap/ui/Device",
  "kristal/apps/agreements/model/models",
  "kristal/apps/agreements/controller/ErrorHandler"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models, ErrorHandler) {
  "use strict";

  return UIComponent.extend("kristal.apps.agreements.Component", {

    metadata: {
      manifest: "json"
    },

    init: function() {
      UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this._oErrorHandler = new ErrorHandler(this);
      this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
      this.setModel(models.createFLPModel(), "FLP");
      this.getRouter().initialize();
    },

    destroy: function() {
      this._oErrorHandler.destroy();
      // call the base component's destroy function
      UIComponent.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    getContentDensityClass: function() {
      if (this._sContentDensityClass === undefined) {
        // check whether FLP has already set the content density class; do nothing in this case
        if (jQuery(document.body).hasClass("sapUiSizeCozy") || jQuery(document.body).hasClass("sapUiSizeCompact")) {
          this._sContentDensityClass = "";
        } else if (!Device.support.touch) { // apply "compact" mode if touch is not supported
          this._sContentDensityClass = "sapUiSizeCompact";
        } else {
          // "cozy" in case of touch support; default for most sap.m controls, but needed for desktop-first controls like sap.ui.table.Table
          this._sContentDensityClass = "sapUiSizeCozy";
        }
      }
      return this._sContentDensityClass;
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was all about moving functionality from the root view to component.js and putting the router initialization into the promise conditions, thank you experts